# How to maintain state with Cloud Functions and Cloud FIrestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How do you maintain the correct state when using Cloud Functions?  They are not guaranteed to fire in the same order that they are called.

Here is a sequence of events:

1. A document is updated `currentState: state1`
2. A document is updated `currentState: state2`
3. The Cloud Function triggers the `state2` update.
4. The Cloud Function triggers the `state1` update.

If your application requires the carrying out of functions in the correct order of states, there's a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions are not guaranteed to fire in order or only once.  Therefore, you must make them idempotent.

You can resolve this in the following way:

1. Always use transactions to update the state, so that 2 clients don't try and change the state at the same time.
2. Create a state table which manages the state and runs functions based on the current state vs. the previous state.
3. Clients must not change the state to a value less than that which exists currently.

### states.json

```
[
  {"currentState": "state1", "action": "state2", "newStates": ["state2"]},
  {"currentState": "state1", "action": "state3", "newStates": ["state2", "state3"]},
  {"currentState": "state1", "action": "state4", "newStates": ["state2", "state3", "state4"]},
  {"currentState": "state1", "action": "state5", "newStates": ["state2", "state3", "state4", "state5"]},
  {"currentState": "state2", "action": "state3", "newStates": ["state3"]},
  {"currentState": "state2", "action": "state4", "newStates": ["state3", "state4"]},
  {"currentState": "state2", "action": "state5", "newStates": ["state3", "state4", "state5"]},
  {"currentState": "state3", "action": "state4", "newStates": ["state4"]},
  {"currentState": "state3", "action": "state5", "newStates": ["state4", "state5"]},
  {"currentState": "state4", "action": "state5", "newStates": ["state5"]}
]
```

### app.js

```
function processStates (beforeState, afterState) {
  const states = require('../states');
  let newStates;

  // Check the states and set the new state
  try {
    newStates = states.filter(function(e) {return e.currentState == beforeState && e.action == afterState;})[0].newStates;
  }
  catch (err) {
    newStates = null;
  }

  console.log(`newStates: ${newStates}`);

  if (newStates) {
    newStates.forEach(newState) {
      // Process state change here
      switch (newState) {
        case 'state1': {
          // Process state1 change
          break;
        }
        case 'state2': {
          // Process state2 change
          break;
        }
        default: {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have an array of states, you can iterate through the using something like `forEach` or `map` to process the required commands.